# Pegar valor de parametro Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Como eu faria para pegar o valor de uma variável do tipo ParameterFields, onde pelo debug consigo visualizar conforme abaixo, onde no caso seria o value = "000000609", para passar para um outra do tipo string ?

dim dsResultado as string = string.empty
dsResultado = me.crParameterFields(nPosTab).CurrentValues(0).???

[image: parametro]

Veja a forma que no momento acabei fazendo, só não sei se seria a forma mais correta, e segura, caso tenha outra maneira e você pude me dar um alozinho, agradeço ?

For Each discreteDefaultVal As ParameterDiscreteValue In Me.crParameterFields(nPos_Tab).CurrentValues
      Dim cResultado As String = String.Empty
      cResultado = discreteDefaultVal.Value
Next

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, para um melhor entendimento